# Create a table in Oracle using the boolean value (true) as an unique index field

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

Imagine a table CARD_SERVICE with KEY(Id_number, Begin_date, Service_Type), End_date and Is_active.

The table CARD_SERVICE allows a single Id_number have multiples registers with the same service what I do not want to to happen.

I could change the table CARD_SERVICE to: KEY(Id_number, Service_Type),Begin_date, End_date and Is_active and now I can have only one single service type per id_number however I could not keep the previous services that are set as False in Is_active so the field is_active loses its use.

So I would like to know if it is possible to set a value of a boolean as an unique field in a table in order to create a table that only accepts new entries if there is no active service in a specific service.

best regards

Comment: In what way does setting is_active to false make the field unuseable?

Comment: if it is set as true this means that a service is active so the id cannot add the same service again. If the is_active is set as false it means that the expire date expired or someone deactivated de service and the id can add again this services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following what you want, you could use a unique function-based index to do this:

```
create table card_service (
    id_number number, begin_date date, service_type number, end_date date, 
    is_active varchar2(5),
    constraint ck_is_active check (is_active in ('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
);

Table created.

create unique index ui_card_service on card_service (
    case when is_active = 'TRUE' then id_number else null end,
    case when is_active = 'TRUE' then service_type else null end
);

Index created.
```

Null values aren't included in the index, so you'll only have index 'entries' for the `TRUE` records, and applying the `case` statement to both fields means the result will still be unique over those two columns.

Trying to insert two records for the same `id_number` and `service_type`, both with `is_active` set to `TRUE`, fails:

```
insert into card_service values (1, date '2013-01-01', 1, null, 'TRUE');

1 row created.

insert into card_service values (1, date '2013-01-02', 1, null, 'TRUE');

insert into card_service values (1, date '2013-01-02', 1, null, 'TRUE')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UI_CARD_SERVICE) violated
```

Updating the existing record to `FALSE` first allows a new `TRUE` to be added;

```
update card_service set is_active = 'FALSE'
where id_number = 1 and service_type = 1 and is_active = 'TRUE';

1 row updated.

insert into card_service values (1, date '2013-01-02', 1, null, 'TRUE');

1 row created.
```

And you can keep doing that:

```
update card_service set is_active = 'FALSE'
where id_number = 1 and service_type = 1 and is_active = 'TRUE';

1 row updated.

insert into card_service values (1, date '2013-01-03', 1, null, 'TRUE');

1 row created.
```

You can add `TRUE` records for other combinations:

```
insert into card_service values (1, date '2013-01-04', 2, null, 'TRUE');
insert into card_service values (2, date '2013-01-05', 1, null, 'TRUE');
insert into card_service values (2, date '2013-01-06', 2, null, 'TRUE');
```

So you end up with:

```
select * from card_service;

 ID_NUMBER BEGIN_DAT SERVICE_TYPE END_DATE  IS_AC
---------- --------- ------------ --------- -----
         1 01-JAN-13            1           FALSE
         1 02-JAN-13            1           FALSE
         1 03-JAN-13            1           TRUE
         1 04-JAN-13            2           TRUE
         2 05-JAN-13            1           TRUE
         2 06-JAN-13            2           TRUE
```

It would be more normal to keep a separate history table with the (presumably old) records though, so your main table only ever has current records (whether `TRUE` or `FALSE`).